# regex matches in rubular, not in java

Tags: java, regex

Im having problems getting some regex expressions to work using java.util.regex's pattern matchers. I have the following expression:

```
(?=^.{1,6}$)(?=^\d{1,5}(,\d{1,3})?$)
```

i test matches against the following strings:

```
12345  (match OK)
123456 (no match)
123,12 (match OK)
```

When i test it out on the following sites it seems to work perfectly:

http://rubular.com , ok

http://www.regextester.com/ , ok

http://myregextester.com/index.php , ok

However i cant seem to get it to match anything in my java program. Also, an online java regex tester gives the same result (no matches) :

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html  No matches ???

I don't have a clue why i can't get this to work in java, but seems to work in a lot of other regex engines?

**Edit:** this was the non-working code. Excuse typo's , i cant copy/paste from my code-pc to stackoverflow.

```
String inputStr = "12345";
String pattern = "(?=^.{1,6}$)(?=^\\d{1,5}(,\\d{1,3})?$)";
Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile(pattern);
System.out.println("Matches? "+regexp.matcher(inputStr).matches());
System.out.println(inputStr.matches(pattern));
```

Comment: What method are you using for matching in Java?

Comment: Please show your (non-working) code in Java.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to match and provide the Java code you are using this regex in?

Comment: Another thing is the regex does zero-length assertion - which means that the whole regex will match an empty string if both assertions are true, but part of the input are still captured in the capturing group inside the assertion.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to escape the `\`s in the pattern. Then if you use `matches()`, Java tries to match against the entire string, so it will return false unless you either remove the second lookahead or add a `.*` at the end.

This produces the right output in Java:

```
    String regex = "(?=^.{1,6}$)^\\d{1,5}(,\\d{1,3})?$";
    System.out.println("12345".matches(regex)); 
    System.out.println("123456".matches(regex)); 
    System.out.println("123,12".matches(regex));
```

And so does this expression:

```
    String regex = "(?=^.{1,6}$)(?=^\\d{1,5}(,\\d{1,3})?$).*";
```

Answer (score 2):

It's working correctly.  You're probably using the `matches()` method, which expects the regex to match *and consume* the whole string.  Your regex doesn't consume anything because it's just a couple of lookaheads.  On the RegexPlanet site, look at the `find()` column and you'll see the results you expect.  In your Java code, you have to create a Matcher object so you can use its `find()` method.

Comment: Thanks all, problem seemed to be as indicated above in different wordings by different people that nothing was consumed. Adding a .* at the end of the regex string fixes everything. 

For completeness i added a few lines of code to my question. Guess i need to read a bit more and update my knowledge of this part of regular expressions!

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the tools is, that in one case it tries to find a match in the other it tries to match the whole string. If you use string.matches(regex) in java, this will return false for all of your inputs as you do not match the whole string with your lookahead expression. Either you append a `.*` as Keppil suggests, or you use the Matcher class:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(text);
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match found");
}
```